# Struts 1.x and tiles 1.1 integration

Tags: java, servlets, struts, tiles

I am trying to integrate struts 1.x with tiles 1.1 but I am facing problems.

Here's snippet of struts-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
<!-- ..... -->
<!-- ..... -->
        <action path="/listcategories"
  type="com.wrox.begjsp.ch28.bookstore.controller.ListCategoriesAction"
  scope="request">
                <forward name="success" path="list.categories"/>
        </action>
<!-- ..... -->
        <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
        <set-property property="definitions-debug" value="2" />
        <set-property property="definitions-parser-details" value="2" />
        <set-property property="definitions-parser-validate" value="true" />
        </plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

And here's snippet of tiles-defs.xml (referenced from struts-config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.1//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/tiles-config_1_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

        <definition name="view.abstract" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/standard-layout.jsp">
        <put name="header"      value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/header.jsp" />
        <put name="menu"        value="bookstore.menu" />
        <put name="base"        value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/base.jsp" />
        </definition>

        <definition name="list.categories"  extends="view.abstract">
        <put name="body"        value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/category-list.jsp" />
        </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

When com.wrox.begjsp.ch28.bookstore.controller.ListCategoriesAction Action succeed, we get some strange exception stating that, the path attribute cannot have a value doesn't starting by / which is "list.categories", which means, it cannot interpret that is not a path but a definition defined in tiles-defs.xml.

I am not a tiles guru, but I think it should know how to interpret this value!

Comment: FWIW, I can tell you your settings in XML are right. I have exactly the same from an old project of mine. Can you post the exact exception?